# Keystroke event in Python

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using python 2.7 and Qt4. I need to have a find dialog after ctrl+F keyboard press. I am using this piece of code for test but I guess this method is never executed in my class. I would appreciate if you would guide me.

My first problem is that when the key is pressed, this method is not called at all!
Secondly, how to combine two keys like ctrl and F. 
Thirdly, how can I call a dialog.
I am new in python, I appreciate if you would help me out...

```
  def find(self, event):
     print("I am here")
     key = event.key()
     if QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
         #show find dialog
         reply=QMessageBox.question(self,'Message',"Find Dialog",QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No,QMessageBox.No)
         if reply==QMessageBox.Yes:
             event.accept()
         else:
             event.ignore()
```

Comment: use this as a reference for key enums: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#Key-enum

Comment: thanks, how can I use a combination of key strokes?

Comment: use `Qt.KeyboardModifier`, it will contain `Qt.ControlModifier` if control is pressed. From http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum

Comment: @OrclUser, use the approach ekhumoro suggested to you in his answer, this is the best way to assign keyboard shortcuts to your application. Add the shortcut in QMenuBar actions of your application window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to set up keyboard shortcuts is with a [QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html) in a menu; or if there are no menus, with a bare [QShortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html).

The key sequences themselves (e.g. Ctrl+F), can be constructed with a [QKeySequence](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html).

The script below shows two different ways to set up a shortcut to open a dialog:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        action = menu.addAction('&Open')
        action.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence('Ctrl+F'))
        action.triggered.connect(self.handleFind)
        shortcut = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence('F3'), self)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.handleFind)
        label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        label.setText('<center>Press Ctrl+F or F3<center>')
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

    def handleFind(self):
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(
            self, 'Message', 'Find Dialog',
            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            print('Yes')
        else:
            print('No')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect reply..One question: what if I have a Qwidget instead of QMainWindow? because I tried this but widget has no attribute 'menuBar'

Comment: It is possible to add a [QMenuBar](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenubar.html) to other widgets, but it would be unusual to do so, and much harder to implement correctly. However, if you don't need a menubar, just use QShortcut as in the example. Having said that, though, by far the best and easiest option would be to just swap your QWidget for a QMainWindow.

Answer (score 1):

The enum for the F key is `Qt.Key_F`, not `Qt.F`.

For control, you can do something like this:

```
if QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
```

or, if you want to ignore other keyboard modifiers, do this:

```
if QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers() | QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
```

Comment: are you going to post the problem?

Comment: The method is not executed at all, I've put that print message print("I am here") for test. But by pressing the keys, i don't see the message in my console.

Comment: you need to add the stuff from my answer to your code. It's not in there yet, or you haven't posted it.

Comment: Now by pressing the Ctrl, i should see the dialog message "Find Dialog", right?

Comment: that's not how it works. It will print the "Find Dialog" message if you are holding ctrl when that bit of your code runs. There's nothing in there that waits for a keypress.